# Remove host ssh

Tags: ssh, fedora, host, ssh-keygen

I'm working with Fedora33 and I have a problem with a ssh host connection (i'm just trying to remove it)

I have a pop up from Openssh that ask me for the host password

> host.name password:

But i have not the password asked, i just want to remove that connection.

I tried to remove the host key like that

> ssh-keygen -R 'ett.nacre-solutions.com'

but now i have an other pop up that i can't remove with this message :

> The authenticity of host host.name can't be established.
> ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:(random.caracters).
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?

How can i really remove that automatic connection ? (The pop appears approximately every 5min)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- `cat .ssh/known_hosts`
- Find the IP of 'ett.nacre-solutions.com' (if 'ett.nacre-solutions.com' was the last remote you connected to, the last IP in `known_hosts` belongs to it).
- `ssh-keygen -R <IP>`

I suspect that you can't remove it because you're passing the web page instead of the IP.

Comment: I already did that ... when i did it the second popup started to appear every 5min ...

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but did you try to reboot your PC? If you have, try passing `systemctl stop sshd` and `systemctl disable sshd` as `sudo` to stop the SSH daemon. This is a less than optimal fix, but I will try to reproduce the issue to see if I can fix it.

Comment: even with the sshd desactivated, the pop up continues to be displayed (and appears after closing) ...

Comment: This is very odd... use `mv ~/.ssh /path/to/different/location` and reboot. If that doesn't work, you might have to try to `ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" user@host` but, be warned: this makes it so that it automatically accepts the key! Or, you could try to back up the `.ssh` folder, and reinstall `openssh`.